# Doctrine Metadata Cache strange behaviour in ClassMetadata

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

My project is developed on PHP7
using

- Symfony 3.1.0
- Doctrine Bundle 1.6.3

I've recognized an error, when changed all **doctrine cache drivers** (query_cache_driver, result_cache_driver, metadata_cache_driver) to different from an *array* type (ex. memcached, redis) and while was perfoming *cache:clear* command (only on production server with Debian8). As output i got

```
[1]    15665 segmentation fault  bin/console cache:clear
```

Then I've started debuging using:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

because this command do 2 same things (validateMapping, chechSync), and this command also outputs something interesting: *it happens that all tables are not in sync, and all tables has same structure (all columnNames in all metadata are equal)*

1. validate mapping

   public function validateMapping()
    {

   ```
   $errors = array();
   $cmf = $this->em->getMetadataFactory();
   $classes = $cmf->getAllMetadata();

   foreach ($classes as $class) {
       if ($ce = $this->validateClass($class)) {
           $errors[$class->name] = $ce;
       }
   }

   return $errors;
   ```

   }
2. check sync

   public function schemaInSyncWithMetadata()
   {

   ```
   $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->em);

   $allMetadata = $this->em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();

   return count($schemaTool->getUpdateSchemaSql($allMetadata, true)) == 0;
   ```

   }

Both of this methods use **AbstractClassMetadataFactory::getMetadataFor** method. This method works correctly when all metadata is clear, but when i run command second time, when this block of code is called:

```
$this->loadedMetadata[$realClassName] = $cached;

$this->wakeupReflection($cached, $this->getReflectionService());
```

Now we can see, that *$cached* is saved into internal array. *$cached* at now time, at this block of code, **is correct array**, all *columnNames* are correct.

But when *getMetadataFor* is called secondly, in the 2nd step of the command, this block of code (in the beginning of the method) which uses that internal array, starts output wrong metadata:  (all columnNames are equal and not correct, when all referenced data about class is correct)

```
public function getMetadataFor($className)
{
    if (isset($this->loadedMetadata[$className])) {
        return $this->loadedMetadata[$className];
    }
```

Any ideas why this is happen? Maybe any solutions which can be helpful?

---

Comment: Did you try clearing doctrine metadata cache?

Comment: Of course i've tried, after clearing metadata cache everything works perfectly just once, but then, when doctrine used cache generated before, system got broken.